# Android GCM get instance id bug

Tags: android

When I try to get InstanceID from the GCM per [the doc](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation), Android Studio complains about missing context parameter. The documentation doesn't mention that. How do I resolve this? Do I simply pass context as such:

```
String iid = InstanceID.getInstance(this).getID();
```

Comment: Is your object calling this method a `Context` or subclass such as `Activity`?

Comment: @ ianhanniballake The docs say String iid = InstanceID.getInstance().getID(); but AS wants to pass Context. I am calling this from Activity and would like to send it to backend once I successfully get the Instance ID from GCM servers. I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as per the [InstanceID Javadoc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID#getInstance(android.content.Context)), you must pass a `Context` to `InstanceID.getInstance()` - be that your Activity or another context.

Comment: I've filed a bug with the documentation team to get the docs updated.

Comment: Note: the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation) has now been updated to reflect that you must pass in a `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            token = instanceID.getToken(ApplicationConstants.SENDER_ID,
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I tried this and I get: java.io.IOException: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE. Any suggestions?

Comment: In this code you see ApplicationConstants.SENDER_ID this is your project number from developer console you first create api key and project number from google developer console it will fix this exception. good luck

Comment: Hi ashan - any follow up on the MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE issue?  I am seeing that, too.

Comment: @jason.zissman, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214685/unable-to-get-token-on-api-level-17. Install Play Market on emulator.