# Unable to get token on API level 17

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am running these commands in order to get a token:

```
  InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
  String token = instanceID.getToken(Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
                             GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

But getting this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE
            at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
            at autofocus.com.autofocus.activity.ItemListActivity$4.doInBackground(ItemListActivity.java:408)
            at autofocus.com.autofocus.activity.ItemListActivity$4.doInBackground(ItemListActivity.java:398)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to official docs:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID#ERROR_MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE

you get this error because

> Tokens can't be generated. Only devices with Google Play are supported.

Testing on emulator without Google Play Services enabled/installed?

Comment: Thanks. I assumed this is the issue, the question is: how do I install Google Play on my emulator device without having Google Play to install it? :)

Comment: there is a well known hack for that.  here is a link for xamarin android player https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator google for similar solution for genymotion. if using official emulator by google, well, stop using and switch to genymotion or xap

Comment: Thanks, works great. I still do not understand why Google didn't put the Google Play built-in on older emulators. It would have saved about 2 hours of my life :)

Comment: for anyone using genymotion you can install gapps clicking on the button "Open Gapps" at the rigth bar

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **gapps** of the version of android in your emulator, if use the genymotion you need to install before the gapps di **Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1** after that, probably will work